# Play I18N library

Tags: playframework, internationalization, lagom

I am trying to read messages using play's I18N library. I am able to read messages using it. However I can only read messages from files under resources folder. I am not able to read messages from any other directory or from root. The reason I want to read from root is I am writing into message files using a Scheduler and because of the hot reloading everthing reloads so I want to read and write messages from root. Is there anyway I can read messages from files using play's I18N library if the files are placed in root.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly describe how Play works: it only reads I18N messages from `resources`. So the answer is: no.